# MS Sync Framework to sync over internet

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

Hi
Does anybody have a good sample or links to samples which shows how I can use MS Sync Framework to sync a SQLCE DB with SQL DB and vice versa over the internet connection

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this sample on msdn codegallery: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/sync/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3423

It uses sync framework 2.1 to collaboratively sync multiple sql compact databases with a central sql server database. Peer-to-peer sync between sql compact databases is also supported in the sample. Everything over WCF, so internet or intranet scenarios are possible.

The whole set of samples supplied by microsoft and showing off different sync scenarios is [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/sync).

Comment: I have tried to follow the MS sample but is very confusing since there are no proper explainations. I guess I will have to follow them and try to understand them